# using pandas i have got from a set of a table where yes and no but i want extract yes and no from it

Tags: python

This are the attributes to the playtennis

```
Outlook   PlayTennis
Overcast  Yes           4
Rain      No            2
          Yes           3
Sunny     No            3
          Yes           2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please explain your question. see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve, add code snippets and more context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you want, but I think you want to filter by column value.

```
# Create dataframe
t = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1": ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"], "col2": [1,2,3,4]})
# Keep only columns with value "Yes"
t[t["col1"] == "Yes"]

  col1  col2
0  Yes     1
2  Yes     3
```